# Sorting elements in struct

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct points{
int i;
int x;
int y;
};
```

And I made an array of the struct and put elements in it. The i element indicates the label of a certain point. Suppose I have 1 2 3 as an input in the array. 1 corresponds to the label of the point (2, 3). Then I tried to sort the x elements:

```
for (a=0; a < i; a++){
                    for (b = 0; b < i; b++){
                        if (pt[b].x > pt[b+1].x){
                        temp1 = pt[b].x;
                        pt[b].x = pt[b+1].x;
                        pt[b+1].x = temp1;
                        }                       
                    }                               
                }
```

It was sorted correctly. Now when I printed the i (label), it did not correspond with the x element when sorted. In short, only the x element moved. I want to make the i and y move with the x as it is sorted. What should I do?

Comment: You are just changing the value of x, neither the value of y or i

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just swapping `x` you need to swap all the data so that the entire array of structures gets sorted.

You could do this with a separate function, for clarity:

```
void swap_points(struct points *pa, struct points *pb)
{
  const struct points tmp = *pa;
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = tmp;
}
```

Then call that instead of the three inner-most lines of code in your sort.

You really should just use [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to do this, it's much simpler:

```
static int compare_points(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
  const struct points *pa = va, *pb = vb;

  return pa->i < pb->i ? -1 : pa->i > pb->i;
}

qsort(pt, i, sizeof pt[0], compare_points);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually sorting the array, but only the values for i, not the whole structure!

You'll want to use C's `qsort` here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct points
{
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
};

int compare(const struct points *a, const struct points *b)
{
    if (a->i < b->i) return -1;
    if (a->i == b->i) return 0;
    if (a->i > b->i) return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct points p[3] = { { 4, 2, 1 }, { 1, 3, 5 }, { 2, 8, 1 } };

    qsort(p, 3, sizeof(struct points), 
        (int (*)(const void*, const void*)) compare);

    printf("{ ");   
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i) 
    {
        printf("{ %d, %d, %d }", p[i].i, p[i].x, p[i].y);
        if (i < 2) printf(", ");
    }
    printf(" }\n");
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: thanks! follow-up question. after the sorting, in case of ties in the x element, how could i sort it in increasing y values?

Comment: You only have to modify the `compare()` function for this. I think you first want to change it from sorting by `i` to sorting by `x`, then edit the case for `a->x == b->x` to consider `y`, i.e. add a nested block of three `if`s (like you have here) inside this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the other elements in the struct too.
I suppose you to write a function which replace the values of an element, like this:

```
void copyPoints(point1* a, point2* b)
{
    int temp = a->i;
    a->i = b->i;
    b->i = temp;
    temp = a->x;
    a->x = b->x;
    b->x = temp;
    temp = a->y;
    a->y = b->y;
    b->y = temp;
}
```

Then modify the code like this:

```
for (a=0; a < i; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        if (pt[b].x > pt[b+1].x)
            copyPoints(&(pt[b]),&(pt[b+1]));  
    }                               
}
```